# How can i change opened windows list placement to vertical in gnome?

Tags: gnome

Can't find this option in gnome-tweak-tool. Should I install any extension?

I need something like this: [image]

Answer (score 0):

the recent Gnome should have this fix, as per http://kojevnikov.com/vertical-panel-in-gnome.html

OR

alternatively, use XFCE 4.10 and above